# cannot reach docker container even its connected to a port

Tags: linux, docker, curl, docker-compose

ı am trying to use a container and I came across a problem. when I curl localhost:8000 inside the container it connects but when I try to go there it says unable to connect. I am providing a screenshot, my YAML file, and my dockerfile.devel in case that helps. Thanks already.
[i curled inside the container and it connected to the port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6PbY.png)

my yaml file

```
version: "2"

services:
  cuckoo:
    privileged: true
    image: cuckoo-docker:2.0.7
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: src/Dockerfile.devel
    ports:
      - "8888:8000"
      - "2042:2042"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - mongo
      - postgres
    networks:
     - cuckoo
    restart: always
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    extra_hosts:
      - "libvirt.local:172.30.201.1"

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
     - cuckoo
    restart: always

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: cuckoo
    networks:
     - cuckoo
    restart: always

networks:
  cuckoo:
    driver: bridge
```

my dockerfile.devel

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV container docker
ENV LC_ALL C
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN sed -i 's/# deb/deb/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt update \
    && apt full-upgrade -y \
    && apt install -y systemd systemd-sysv \
    && apt clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/ \
    && ls | grep -v systemd-tmpfiles-setup | xargs rm -f $1

RUN rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/* \
    /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev* \
    /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl* \
    /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/plymouth* \
    /lib/systemd/system/systemd-update-utmp*

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y python2.7 python-pip python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev python-virtualenv python-setuptools libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev swig qemu-kvm libvirt-bin \
    ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils python-libvirt tcpdump libguac-client-rdp0 libguac-client-vnc0 libguac-client-ssh0 guacd pcregrep libpcre++-dev autoconf automake libtool \
    build-essential libjansson-dev libmagic-dev supervisor mongodb postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev nano bison byacc tor suricata flex\
    && apt clean

RUN set -x \
    && cd /tmp/ \
    && git clone --recursive --branch 'v3.11.0' https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara.git \
    && cd /tmp/yara \
    && ./bootstrap.sh * \
    && sync \
    && ./configure --with-crypto --enable-magic --enable-cuckoo --enable-dotnet \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && cd /tmp \
    && git clone --recursive --branch '2.6.1' https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility.git \
    && cd volatility \
    && python setup.py build install \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*


RUN pip install -U --no-cache-dir pyrsistent==0.16.1 MarkupSafe==1.1.1 itsdangerous==1.1.0 configparser==4.0.2 distorm3==3.4.4 setuptools pycrypto ujson  cryptography psycopg2 jsonschema==3.2.0 werkzeug==0.16.0 Mako==1.1.0 python-editor==1.0.3 urllib3==1.25.7 tlslite==0.4.9 SFlock==0.3.3 tlslite-ng==0.7.6 pyOpenSSL==18.0.0

  

RUN apt update && apt install -y vim
COPY cuckoo /opt/cuckoo
WORKDIR /opt/cuckoo
RUN python stuff/monitor.py
RUN python setup.py sdist develop
RUN cuckoo init
RUN cuckoo community


COPY etc/conf /root/.cuckoo/conf
COPY etc/supervisord.conf /root/.cuckoo/
COPY etc/cuckoo.sh /opt/

RUN chmod +x /opt/cuckoo.sh

CMD ["/opt/cuckoo.sh"]
```

Comment: Can you reduce this Docker setup to a [mcve]?  Do you need both systemd and supervisord, or even either at all?  Multiple databases, an obsolete version of Python, multiple interactive text editors?  The obsolete Compose `links:` and `expose:` options?  Try to reduce this setup to the smallest thing that demonstrates the error, and clearly state how you've invoking it and what error you get (include the error as plain text and not a link to an image).

Answer (score 0):

When you set

```
    ports:
      - "8888:8000"
```

this means that the port **8000 in the container** is mapped to the port **8888 in the host machine**
so if you curl from the host machine you have to curl port 8888

Comment: I changed to 8888 to 8000 and curled it connected again but this time it said the connection was reset (the container was up as well)

Comment: check docker logs

Comment: I checked the logs and it says INFO gave up: cuckoo-daemon entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

Comment: try to restart `docker-compose restart`